# xmlwriter , it's being used by another process

Tags: c#

Here, i created a class, and what i am trying to accomplish is to write the contents from the list into an xml file.

1) At first run, it creates the file and trows an error here: Token EndElement in state EndRootElement would result in an invalid XML document

```
 public static void SaveCellPhoneProducts(List<ProducCellPhone> LocalProducts)
    {
        XmlWriterSettings localSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        localSettings.Indent = true;
        localSettings.IndentChars = ("   ");

        //second run, error Occurr here
        //xml writer object, CellPhoneProduct
        XmlWriter xmlOut = XmlWriter.Create(path, localSettings);

        xmlOut.WriteStartDocument();
        xmlOut.WriteStartElement("Cell");

        foreach(ProducCellPhone localProduct in LocalProducts)
        {
            WriteCellPhoneProductBase(localProduct, xmlOut);
        }
        //first Run error is thrown in here.  
        xmlOut.WriteEndElement();
        xmlOut.Close();
    }
```

2) When i rerun on the second time, the error is in same method.

```
 public static void SaveCellPhoneProducts(List<ProducCellPhone> LocalProducts)
    {
        XmlWriterSettings localSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        localSettings.Indent = true;
        localSettings.IndentChars = ("   ");

        //xml writer object, CellPhoneProduct
        XmlWriter xmlOut = XmlWriter.Create(path, localSettings);

        xmlOut.WriteStartDocument();
        xmlOut.WriteStartElement("Cell");

        foreach(ProducCellPhone localProduct in LocalProducts)
        {
            WriteCellPhoneProductBase(localProduct, xmlOut);
        }
        xmlOut.WriteEndElement();
        xmlOut.Close();
    }
```

The whole class i here:

```
class ProductCellPhoneDB
{
    private const string path = @"..\..\CellPhoneProducts.xml";

    public static List<ProducCellPhone> GetCellPhoneProducts()
    {
        List<ProducCellPhone> localCellPhoneProducts = 
            new List<ProducCellPhone>();

        XmlReaderSettings localSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        localSettings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
        localSettings.IgnoreComments = true;

        XmlReader xmlIn = (XmlReader.Create(path,localSettings));
        if (xmlIn.ReadToDescendant("Cell"))
        {
            do
            {
                ProducCellPhone localProduct = null;
                xmlIn.ReadStartElement("Cell");
                localCellPhoneProducts.Add(localProduct);
            }
            while (xmlIn.ReadToNextSibling("Cell"));
        }
        xmlIn.Close();
        return localCellPhoneProducts;       
    }

    public static void SaveCellPhoneProducts(List<ProducCellPhone> LocalProducts)
    {
        XmlWriterSettings localSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        localSettings.Indent = true;
        localSettings.IndentChars = ("   ");

        //Error Occurr here
        //xml writer object, CellPhoneProduct, error is being used by other process?
        XmlWriter xmlOut = (XmlWriter.Create(path, localSettings));

        xmlOut.WriteStartDocument();
        xmlOut.WriteStartElement("Cell");

        foreach(ProducCellPhone localProduct in LocalProducts)
        {
            WriteCellPhoneProductBase(localProduct, xmlOut);
        }
        //ERROR  Token EndElement in state EndRootElement would result in an invalid XML document
        xmlOut.WriteEndElement();
        xmlOut.Close();
    }

    private static void ReadCellphoneProductBase(XmlReader xmlIn, ProducCellPhone localProduct)
    {
        localProduct.Iemi = xmlIn.ReadElementContentAsString();
        localProduct.Model = xmlIn.ReadContentAsString();
        localProduct.Price = xmlIn.ReadContentAsDecimal();            
    }

    private static void WriteCellPhoneProductBase(ProducCellPhone localProduct,
        XmlWriter xmlout)
    {
        xmlout.WriteElementString("IEMI", localProduct.Iemi);
        xmlout.WriteElementString("Model", localProduct.Model);
        xmlout.WriteElementString("Price", Convert.ToString(localProduct.Price));
        xmlout.WriteEndElement();
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks community. !

Comment: The second error is because the underlying file was not closed. An [`XmlWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) owns OS resources (such as the file handle), and therefore implements the `IDisposable` interface. When using one, you need to wrap it in a `using` block, as in `using (var xmlOut = XmlWriter.Create(path, localSettings)) { ... the rest of the code ... }`. The same is true for the `XmlReader` you are using.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add (a part of) the xml file you are reading to your question.

Answer (score 1):

**The first error**
 you get is likely because the `WriteStartElement` and `WriteEndElement` calls are not matched. You do `xmlOut.WriteStartElement("Cell");` once, but do `xmlout.WriteEndElement();` several times, once for each `ProducCellPhone` in `LocalProducts`, plus another time after the `foreach`.

To solve this (if I guessed your XML document structure right), you should change your `WriteCellPhoneProductBase` method to:

```
private static void WriteCellPhoneProductBase(ProducCellPhone localProduct,
    XmlWriter xmlout)
{
    xmlOut.WriteStartElement("Cell");
    xmlout.WriteElementString("IEMI", localProduct.Iemi);
    xmlout.WriteElementString("Model", localProduct.Model);
    xmlout.WriteElementString("Price", Convert.ToString(localProduct.Price));
    xmlout.WriteEndElement();
}
```

And remove the `WriteStartElement` and `WriteEndElement` lines from `SaveCellPhoneProducts` (see below).

**The second error** is probably because the `XmlWriter`  used when you got the first error was not disposed and has not closed the file handle. You should always use a `using` block to ensure `IDisposable` resources get disposed, also when an exception occurs. You should change your method to:

```
public static void SaveCellPhoneProducts(List<ProducCellPhone> LocalProducts)
{
    //xml writer settings
    XmlWriterSettings localSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    localSettings.Indent = true;
    localSettings.IndentChars = ("   ");

    using (var xmlOut = XmlWriter.Create(path, localSettings))
    {
        xmlOut.WriteStartDocument();

        //write each product on xml file
        foreach(ProducCellPhone localProduct in LocalProducts)
            WriteCellPhoneProductBase(localProduct, xmlOut);

        xmlOut.WriteEndDocument()
    }
}
```

For your `GetCellPhoneProducts` follow the same `using` block approach.

Comment: Interesting. A file was created, i use notepad to verify if it was in deed writen.  -- thanks for the suggestion.